# Why is char *A able to hold strings while char A cannot?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am having trouble understanding why a character pointer is able to hold a string.

Shouldn't it be like character, only should be able to hold a character.

Comment: `char*` is a pointer to a character. `char` is a character.

Comment: A string is not a character. A string is a sequence of characters. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP: A string is a sequence of characters, and `char*` points to only one of them (the first). The crucial part is that the sequence of chars is zero-terminated. Therefore, you know only the first but can find all following characters. (And the two actions are O(1) and O(N), so definitely distinct). +1 for figuring out that something is missing in your mental model of string and asking it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Char pointers are assumed to point to the *beginning* of a string.
The pointer itself points to the first character in the string, and code using the pointer assumes that the rest of the string follows it in memory, until it reaches a `\0`.

Comment: To give a concrete example of "code using the pointer": `printf("Hello")` is equivalent to passing the **pointer** to the character `'H'` to `printf`. Whereas, trying to pass `'H'` itself, as in `printf('H')`, will give an error because printf expects a const char pointer as an argument . `printf` assumes the rest of the string (`ello`) follows `H` in memory, until it reaches `\0`, as SLaks explained.

Answer (score 9):

Picture:

```
+---+---+---+----+------
| A | B | C | \0 | ???
+---+---+---+----+------
  ^
  |---char*
```

Yes, each `char*` can point to only a single char at a time. But C++ strings like `"ABC"` are stored in memory as a contiguous sequence, without holes and with a 0 char at the end. Therefore, if you have the pointer to 'A', `++pointer` will get you the pointer to 'B'. And you also know that you can do `++` until you find that last `'\0'`. (Which is exactly what `strlen("ABC")` does - use `++` 3 times to find the 0, so it returns 3.)

Answer (score 3):

a character pointer does not hold anything except an address.
This address is that of the first element of a char array (or can be at least).
in essence `char*` is the same as `char[]`

A char on the other hand is a value type and cannot hold more than one byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a;
```

is a pointer(aka address/location expressed as number) to a character. It means that is does not hold a string (a sequence of characters) itself. In fact **char *a**'s size (depending on various factors) is 4 bytes. Such a variable may point to actual location where your string really is (its first character followed by others and terminated by 0). In C/C++ it will be so called ASCIIZ ie. sequence of chars terminated by zero.

On the contrary this:

```
char a;
```

is a variable (usually 8bits) that stores just **one** character (plain ASCII char - not unicode codepoint etc)

**Update:**
Of course MSalters below is right - the string may just contain anything ie. may be composed of any values that char can hold and this does not have (although usually is) to be interpreted as ASCII.

Comment: _probably_ 4 bytes, _probably_ ASCII. The usual name is therefore NTBS, Null Terminated Byte String.

Comment: Indeed probably that is why I wrote "(depending on various factors)"

Answer (score 0):

it's actually simple:

char *A is a character pointer. it's another way of initializing an array of characters, which is what a string is.

char A, on the other hand, is a single char. it can't be more than one char.

See this conversation for more info:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13343/

Answer (score 0):

Think string "abc" as a list of `Char` "a", "b" and "c", `Char A` is a variable of type `Char`, which cannot represent string "abc". `Char *A` is a pointer of type `Char`, it can point to a `Char` type variable. `Char *A` can be used to point to the first element of string, in this case, "a".

Answer (score 0):

In C, (null terminated) strings are represented in memory in sequential memory cells of characters (their bytes - but I am not going to make it more complex on byte align etc.), with the last sequential character the '\0' (terminating):

```
char* str = "test"; -----> |t|e|s|t|\0|
```

`char` type is about one character only:

```
char ch = 'a'; -----> |a|
```

Now, in C++, you can either use C-style strings (`char*` types) or the `string` class of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

***##char array or char pointer doesn't hold the string but only points to the Base Address##***

A **string** is union of characters sequentially stored in Memory Locations. Thus if the memory address of the first char is known we can know the other addresses by incrementing (by the size taken by the data type. In this case it's 1 byte) the Memory Address.

A string is a char array and an array's name points to the memory address where the first character is stored (**Base Address**). String functions work by manipulating that Memory Address *(not sure about that but I can't think of any other way)*.

On the other hand, a char pointer also points to the Memory Location of a character.
Thus can be used the same way by string functions.

Thus strings can be declared using char arrays or char pointers...